# Changes in .forEach() have no effect?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

So let me preface this with the fact that I'm doing this coding in Codecademy so maybe its just that being weird.

I am trying to remove all punctuation from an array (dupBW) and set everything to lowercase.

My code works fine within the forEach, the console.log shows that. But then dupBW is unaffected when I log it out at the end.

Thanks for the help.

```
  dupBW.forEach(dupWord => {
    if(puncArray.includes(dupWord[dupWord.length-1])) {
      dupWord = dupWord.slice(0, dupWord.length-1);
      dupWord = dupWord.toLowerCase();
      console.log(dupWord);
    }
  });
  
  console.log(dupBW.join(' '));
```

Comment: What you’re looking for is probably `Array.prototype.map`, by returning `dupWord` in the callback. In foreach you’re not assigning it to anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `String.prototype.replace()` with a RegExp to match the punctuation?

Comment: `dupWord` is a copy of the string at the current index in `dupBW`. Modifying that copy doesn't affect the content of `dupBW`.

Comment: @Andreas What's more, you cannot modify strings at all, the only thing that's modified in the code is the `dupWord` local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `forEach` to `map` and return `dupWord` at the end, and it will work; by assigning the array to the newly returned one. `Array.prototype.map` returns a new array with the return values of the callbacks.

```js
dupBW = dupBW.map(dupWord => {
    if(puncArray.includes(dupWord[dupWord.length-1])) {
      dupWord = dupWord.slice(0, dupWord.length-1);
      dupWord = dupWord.toLowerCase();
      console.log(dupWord);
    }
      return dupWord;
  });
  
  console.log(dupBW.join(' '));
```

Comment: `map` does *not* mutate original array. It *creates a new array*, that you assign to the same variable `dupBW` (assuming it was not declared with `const`).

Answer (score 0):

If you see in the documentation for [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you will find that forEach does not modify the array it is called on. For that, you can use regular for loop or map or reduce.

You can do the following,

```
let res = dupBW.map(dupWord => {
    if(puncArray.includes(dupWord[dupWord.length-1])) {
      dupWord = dupWord.slice(0, dupWord.length-1);
      dupWord = dupWord.toLowerCase();
      console.log(dupWord);
    }
    return dupWord;
  });
  
  console.log(res.join(' '));
```

Comment: _"that forEach should not update"_ - It does not modify the array it is called on. But no-one is stopping you from doing it "by hand": `.forEach((dupWord, index) => { ... dupBW[index] = dupWord; })`

Comment: Agreed. @Andreas. My bad. Updating.